# Laravel oneToMany accessor usage in eloquent and datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables, eloquent, laravel-datatables

On my User model I have the following:

```
public function isOnline()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Accounting', 'userid')->select('rtype')->latest('ts');
}
```

The accounting table has activity records and I'd like this to return the latest value for field 'rtype' for a userid when used.

In my controller I am doing the following:

```
    $builder = App\User::query()
        ->select(...fields I want...)
        ->with('isOnline')
        ->ofType($realm); 

    return $datatables->eloquent($builder)
        ->addColumn('info', function ($user) {
            return $user->isOnline;
        }
    })
```

However I don't get the value of 'rtype' for the users in the table and no errors.

Comment: Read docs of Laravel

Comment: If you care to expand on your answer it would be appreciated. I've read through the relationship and querying relationship docs and am looking for assistance as I cannot seemingly get the result I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts.](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer, and mark as accepted. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not defining your relationship correctly. Your `isOnline` method creates a `HasMany` relation but runs the `select` method and then the `latest` method on it, which will end up returning a `Builder` object.

The correct approach is to only return the `HasMany` object from your method and it will be treated as a relation.

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Accounting', 'userid');
}
```

Then if you want an `isOnline` helper method in your `App\User` class you can add one like this:

```
public function isOnline()
{
    // This gives you a collection of \App\Accounting objects
    $usersAccounts = $this->accounts;

    // Do something with the user's accounts, e.g. grab the last "account"
    $lastAccount = $usersAccounts->last();
    if ($lastAccount) {
        // If we found an account, return the rtype column
        return $lastAccount->rtype;
    }

    // Return something else
    return false;
}
```

Then in your controller you can eager load the relationship:

```
$users = User::with('accounts')->get(['field_one', 'field_two]);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with each `App\User` object, such as calling the `isOnline` method.

---

**Edit**

After some further digging, it seems to be the `select` on your relationship that is causing the problem. I did a similar thing in one of my own projects and found that no results were returned for my relation. Adding `latest` seemed to work alright though.

So you should remove the `select` part at very least in your relation definition. When you only want to retrieve certain fields when eager loading your relation you should be able to specify them when using `with` like this:

```
// Should bring back Accounting instances ONLY with rtype field present
User::with('accounts:rtype');
```

This is the case for Laravel 5.5 at least, I am not sure about previous versions. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for more information, under the heading labelled *Eager Loading Specific Columns*

Comment: Thanks for the input, greatly appreciated...

I made some updates:
https://pastebin.com/FCj4UTmT

The issue I'm having now, is that $user->isOnline(); always returns "oops" (for debugging purposes)

The isOnline method *should*, based on the user, query the accounting table for the most recent row (newest) and give the value for 'rtype'

Right now, seemingly, it's not doing that... 

I tried to swap last() for latest('ts') (ts being my timestamp column) but that method isn't available.

Thank you very very much for the assistance thus far.

Comment: So the following works but the controller bits feel super dirty, any advice there?

https://pastebin.com/xyMKwFKz

Comment: All set, this is the final version that works well:

https://pastebin.com/4nB1N30e

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, I've not been active today and hadn't seen your messages. No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonathon

#### USER MODEL

```
public function accounting()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Accounting', 'userid', 'userid');
}

public function isOnline()
{
    $rtype = $this->accounting()
        ->latest('ts')
        ->limit(1)
        ->pluck('rtype')
        ->first();

    if ($rtype == 'Alive') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### CONTROLLER

```
$builder = App\User::with('accounting:rtype')->ofType($filterRealm);

return $datatables->eloquent($builder)
    ->addColumn('info', function (App\User $user) {

    /*
    THIS HAS BEEN SUCCINCTLY TRIMMED TO BE AS RELEVANT AS POSSIBLE.
    ARRAY IS USED AS OTHER VALUES ARE ADDED, JUST NOT SHOWN HERE
    */

    $info[];

    if ($user->isOnline()) {
        $info[] = 'Online';
    } else {
        $info[] = 'Offline';
    }

    return implode(' ', $info);
})->make();
```